# Devise Sign Out/Log Out not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I hate to post another topic about this since there seem to be about a dozen but I can't find any that solve this issue for me.

In my `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
    <%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path %> |
    <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> |
    <%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %>
  <% end %>
```

`routes` look like this:

```
devise_for :users, 
    path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  resources :users
  resources :addresses

  root 'users#index'
  get 'dashboard', to: "users#dashboard"
```

And my local log looks like this:

```
started GET "/users/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 17:47:21 -0700
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"logout"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered users/show.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
```

So like many other topics, it's trying to pass `logout` as the `id`. I have the `:delete` in my `application.html.erb` link, so that's not it.

This is what's in my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

That looks good.

Any ideas? I'm stumped...

Edit: Output from `rake routes`

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/login(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/login(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/logout(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
               addresses GET    /addresses(.:format)           addresses#index
                         POST   /addresses(.:format)           addresses#create
             new_address GET    /addresses/new(.:format)       addresses#new
            edit_address GET    /addresses/:id/edit(.:format)  addresses#edit
                 address GET    /addresses/:id(.:format)       addresses#show
                         PATCH  /addresses/:id(.:format)       addresses#update
                         PUT    /addresses/:id(.:format)       addresses#update
                         DELETE /addresses/:id(.:format)       addresses#destroy
                    root GET    /                              users#index
               dashboard GET    /dashboard(.:format)           users#dashboard
       send_im_home_text GET    /im_home(.:format)             users#im_home
```

Comment: Is your app loading `jquery_ujs`? When you inspect the page is it showing up as included?

Comment: Can you include the output from `rake routes`

Comment: @JosephL Added output from `rake routes`

Comment: @JonathanBender It doesn't appear to be in there

Comment: Agree With Jonathan! Need to have 'jquery_ujs' loaded. Maybe, try shift the hierarchy.

Comment: @Aditya Should the jquery files be in /public or in /assets/javascripts?

Comment: You should have `jquery-rails` in your Gemfile

Comment: @JonathanBender I do...

Comment: Is it listed when you run `bundle list`?

Comment: @JonathanBender Yes it is

Comment: Version 3.0.4, which came stock. I didn't change that

Comment: Just to confirm, in your source you're seeing `data-method="delete"` on the link, but `assets/jquery_ujs.js` is not in your head.

Comment: @JonathanBender That is correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39716/discussion-between-jonathan-bender-and-zack-shapiro)

Comment: @JonathanBender Chat later this evening on this issue?

Comment: Fixed it. It was missing `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` in my `application.html.erb`

Answer (score 2):

Missing `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` in `application.html.erb` as mentioned in comments.